# How to cause a program to end when a certain number of entities are killed

Tags: java

I'm working on a game for a school project and I am trying to make it so that when a certain amount of entities are killed, the game will end. However I am running into an issue with the decreasing of my variable. Here's what I have so far:

```
public class Guy extends StaticEntity {

public int count = 2;

}

public void die(){


     count--;

     if(count == 0){
        System.exit(1);
                   }
```

On the entity dying, it should be decreasing the count variable by one, but after destroying 2 of this entity, it doesn't do anything. If I do it with 1 entity, it works fine.

If you need anything else from my code, I am willing to provide it, this is my first time asking a question on the website so I don't know if I need to provide anything else and I'm a novice at coding.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make your code into a [mcve] so that we can run it and observe the problem.

Answer (score 13):

Use a `static` variable, like this: `public static int count = 2;`

Each and every instance of the class will share the same variable, so that if you change it in one instance, the change will reflect in all instances, created either before or after the change.

Comment: @Lino In your code, each time an entity dies, it decreases its own, entity specific, count by one. However,  other entities don't receive this. Static makes all entities share the variable, so it is decreased universally.

Comment: @Penn I never posted any code but thanks for the explanation ;) as it is useful for future readers and other creatures stumbling over this answer